# Aws lambda + api gateway: only trigger lambda by button click

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws lambda function which runs some python code (which is calling an external api with some extra functions). I attached a trigger, an api gateway, which if I go to the url, the lambda functions runs correctly.

However, I want the lambda function only to be run if they click on a button somewhere on the 'website' of the api-url. Rephrased otherwise, I want the api-url page to have a button, which on click executes the lambda function.
Im think that should be quite easy, however I can't figure out how. Due to the information overload I can't seem to find the right video, document example on how to do it.

- Is the possible? (running the lambda function on click of a button). If so, is there some good documentation of example of this?

I tried to add a button on the api-url page by, on 'method-execution' on the 'api-gateway resource' page, changing the mapping template to text/html instead of json. (a bit like in https://blog.it-playground.eu/display-html-page-using-only-api-gateway/) But then i can't figure out how to run the lambda function onClick of the button. ==> Is this the right start?

(Because its not really a coding issue, I can't really provide any code).

Also, is this question so simply that it shows I simply don't understand the basics enough (and should subsequently go over them again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible. API Gateway exposes REST API. All you need to do is to create some resource and method in API Gateway such as

`GET /posts`

attach your lambda function to it, and hit that API endpoint with some ajax request from your front end (via `fetch`, `axios`, ...) that would  be executed when the button is clicked. Something like:

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch("https://my-api-gateway-url/posts").then() ...
}
```

You can process the response data in `.then` part but don't forget that this is asynchronous coding so you need to handle it as such.

Comment: Should I then have 2 api gateways? The first one to which other people can connect to and as second on which invokes the lambda function and witch i put in the 'fetch'?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by `which other people can connect to` but it doesn't really matter. No, you can create all your endpoints under one API Gateway. You are always hitting just one endpoint with one HTTP request and whether you need one or two API Gateways is unrelated to functionality of individual endpoints unless you need to separate domains such as `www.foo.com` and `www.bar.com`. If you don't need to separate domains then you can easily separate your functionality based on some URL path prefix such as `/api` for JSON data API endpoints.

Comment: With the 'other people can connect to'; Some context, I would give some business people a link and only if they click the button a process should start which for example would refresh underlaying data of a dashboard.

Comment: `I would give some business people a link` - yes, and that is a specific endpoint in API Gateway, not API Gateway itself (whatever that would mean). You just use another link (endpoint) in your JS code to fetch whatever you want it to. Btw, how exactly are you serving your website to those people? Are you planning to serve it from API Gateway? Because that is not the greatest idea in the first place - API Gateway's main purpose is to server REST APIs, not static websites.

Comment: I think its obvious I dont master the fundamentals enough and should go over them again. Regarding how I should serving the website, it would be not more then a webpage with one but (maybe with some log information when the button is clicked)

Comment: Well, it seems so but you don't need to worry about that. If you want to leverage API Gateway in the way you just described then I would suggest you to look into how single page applications are made and then how to serve your static website from S3 and you should be pretty much good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and help :-)